# A SQL query using min() with join having group by and order by

Tags: sql, odbc

I'm using an odbc for PHP.

I used the SQL statement shown below - the `Name` column appeared but the `Time` didn't with an error:

> odbc_result(): Field checktime not found on line 88

I don't know where I went wrong; I'm hoping for your great guidance. Thanks

```sql
SELECT
    u.name, MIN(c.checktime) AS minchecktime
FROM
    userinfo u
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    CHECKINOUT c ON u.USERID = c.USERID
WHERE
    u.defaultdeptid <> 17 AND
    u.defaultdeptid <> 16 AND
    u.defaultdeptid <> 10 AND
    u.defaultdeptid <> 11 AND
    u.defaultdeptid <> 18 AND
    u.defaultdeptid <> 20 AND
    c.checktime >= #2023-12-02 00:01:00# AND
    c.checktime <= #2023-12-02 16:01:00# AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.checktime 
                FROM checkinout c
                WHERE u.USERID = c.USERID 
                GROUP BY c.checktime    
                HAVING c.checktime <= #2023-12-02 07:01:00#
                   AND c.checktime >= #2023-12-02 00:00:00#
                ORDER BY MIN(c.checktime) DESC)
GROUP BY
    u.name
ORDER BY
    MIN(c.checktime) DESC
```

I'm expecting the time column to appear.

Comment: You shouldn't use columns in the `LEFT JOIN` table in `WHERE`. That effectively changes it to `INNER JOIN`, since all the non-matching rows will have `NULL` for those columns.

Comment: In case your query is case sensitive, do both tables `CHECKINOUT` and `checkinout` exist?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? ODBC isn't a database, it's a DB-agnostic API.

Comment: BTW, intead of all those `<>` checks, you can use `u.defaultdeptid NOT IN (...)`

Comment: There's no point in `ORDER BY` in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery. All that matters is whether the row exists, order doesn't matter.